# How to make a SQS delay queue of x hours

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, data-driven-tests

I need a queue to process messages after *x* hours delay. And I need a data-driven all event-based approach not using any schedulers and such.

The scenario is I have some live data that I send to an SNS topic and from there to different SQS queues to be consumed by different AWS Lambda functions.

One of the Lambda functions needs to process the messages after 3 hours delay. However, the maximum delivery delay is 15 minutes. If I read the message for the first time it will be automatically be deleted from SQS as I am using event source mapping triggers to invoke the lambda function.

So, I am wondering how I could avoid deleting the message and make it invisible the first time it is processed?

Any thoughts/help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you not delete the message after first time you read it? Maybe you could get it from the queue, change its visibility to 3h (max 12h) and process it correctly again in 3h.

Comment: As soon as I read them they get automatically deleted by event source mapping!

Comment: @Marcin , I actually had this plan to read it once and leave it there until the visibility timeout reaches the threshold to reprocess again. But, seems like it's getting deleted the first time. I am after a way to avoid this deleting part.

Comment: If you return successful from lambda, yes, event source mapping will assume a message was processed successfully and will delete it. If you fail in lambda after changing the visibility timeout, event source mapping will not delete the message. Instead it will retry to submit it again. I think returning status code other than 200 would be considered a fail? Would have to check that.

Comment: Oh! Good to know I thought only invocation failures would return the msgs to the queue again... so any exception from my lambda would do right? I'll try that right away.. thanks

Comment: I want to say yes..., but not 100% sure of that at this moment. But this is something that small proof-of-concept sqs + lambda can verify.

Answer (score 4):

Amazon SQS will not do what you are requesting. Also, I do not recommend doing any "tricks" to force it to delay.

I would recommend that you look at **AWS Step Functions**. It can orchestrate interaction between AWS Lambda functions and can be configured to **wait (sleep) for a period before invoking an AWS Lambda function**.

Answer (score 1):

I tested it. And it seems doable. I used the below code for tests. However, it does not seem to be "a good practice" way of doing what you want to achieve. I see two main issues:

1. There is limit for in-flight massages of 120,000. So you loose nearly unlimited scaling of your SQS queue.
2. Your metrics will be littered with error invocations and it will be difficult to distinguish real failed invocations from those that failed on purpose.

Thus I would look into other solutions.

```python
import json
import os
import time

import boto3

sqs = boto3.client('sqs')

queue_url = os.environ['QUEUE_URL']

new_visibility_timeout = 120 # seconds

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    print(json.dumps(event))
    
    current_time = time.time()
    
    no_of_new_records = 0
    
    for record in event['Records']:
        
        msg_timestamp = float(record['attributes']['SentTimestamp'])/1000
        
        msg_age = current_time - msg_timestamp
        
        print(f"Message age: {msg_age} seconds")
        
        if msg_age > new_visibility_timeout:
            
            print("Message to be successfully processed and deleted from queue")
            
            response = sqs.delete_message(
                QueueUrl=queue_url,
                ReceiptHandle=record['receiptHandle']
            )
            
            print(response)

        else:
            
            print("Set long visibility timeout")
            
            response = sqs.change_message_visibility(
                QueueUrl=queue_url,
                ReceiptHandle=record['receiptHandle'],
                VisibilityTimeout=new_visibility_timeout
            )
            
            print(response)
            
            no_of_new_records += 1

    if no_of_new_records > 0:
        raise Exception("Fail the lambda")
    
    return {'statusCode': 200}
```

Comment: I tried this, and didn't work for me! even though I raise the exception, the msg still gets deleted..I can see that it's even changing the visibility timeout, but it's not like marking that message as invisible. It just deletes it :|

Comment: Does your lambda have permissions to work with SQS? Also can setup DLQ for the primary SQS queue, so the messages go there if processed incorrectly.

Comment: yes it does, I can call delete message manually as well! but there is no point! since it's deleting the msg no matter what..I think it's the trigger from sqs to lambda which makes this automatic deletion behaviour...If I poll the queue manually it will be working fine

Comment: Do you still use delay queue? I tested it on regular queue with all the default settings. The execution role for lambda also had full sqs permissions. Maybe if you use different settings, you need to adjust the code accordingly. As a proof of concept you can control visibility timeout using code provided.